# Azure Development Fabric Logging Agent crashes on start

Tags: azure, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

When I click debug in visual studio on an Azure project I keep getting the same following error every time:
[image: Windows Azure Development Fabric Logging Agent has stopped working]

In the background, the other parts do run and the emulator runs but none of the logging functions work. I am running a pretty clean Windows 8 install (downloaded from DreamSpark) with a clean Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC installed.
How can I fix whatever is going wrong?

Comment: Which version of VS2012 are you running? The icon seems strange. Is this RTM version or some preview?

Comment: XIII, in his question you'll see that he's using the RC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and discovered that this seem to work

1. If I reboot and then start the azure emulator from the azure command prompt. Works fine.
2. If I then shut down and exit the taskbar icon and restart from the command prompt, I get the error again.
3. Checking the running processes, it seems that dfmonitor.exe does not terminate and continues running.
4. If I terminate dfmonitor.exe and then restart the emulator from the command prompt, it starts up fine without the error.

Answer (score 0):

It started working suddenly without any changes made.